# isNaN() throwing an error when passing a BigInt

Tags: javascript, bigint

Why is the function isNaN() throwing an error when passing a BigInt as parameter?

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number
    at isNaN (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Code to replicate:

```js
let i = BigInt('2');
isNaN(i);
```

Comment: Per the docs *BigInt* is an object. Its not a number.

Comment: `BigInt` cannot be coerced into a number, which is the first thing `isNaN` does.  See [the spec on isNaN](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number) and [the spec on ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)

Comment: Because that is how it has been specified: [`isNaN()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number) -> [`ToNumber()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) -> `BigInt` -> _"Throw a TypeError exception"_

Comment: @Amy *"BigInt cannot be coerced into a number"* - Admittedly slightly pedantic, but I believe it *can*, just not using this method :) For example, `Number(BigInt('2')) === 2` works just fine.

Comment: @TylerRoper Because `Number()` calls [`ToNumeric()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumeric)

Comment: @Andreas Correct! That is the basis for my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an object, if you need convert it to a number you can simply use `Number`, e.g:

```js
let i = BigInt('2');
isNaN(Number(i));

console.log(isNaN(Number(i)));
```

Comment: *"It is an object"*. But, `isNaN({ key: 10 })` doesn't throw an error